# Installing Wine offline

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, wine

I've downloaded Ubuntu for the first time on a old desktop because I want to learn how to use Ubuntu as I would any other OS. But the machine is Ethernet only and I don't really want to buy 20M cable or a power line adapter.

I do have a USB wireless network adapter I dug out. So I've downloaded the driver for it and I've also got 'wine-3.0.tar.xz' file onto a USB stick from a different device and put them on the desktop.

But I don't know how to install the wine file onto the system properly to then run the exe file for the driver... Any help?

I've currently tried:

```bsh
sudo cp ~/desktop/wine-3.0.tar.xz* /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

(which worked as it should.)

Then:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Which didn't work. :(

Comment: Which ubuntu version do you use ? Please add it to your question. You can find releases of each package in the [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/wine) website. After downloading, install them via "sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb "

Comment: Or from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: A .tar.xz is not a software *package*. It's just a compressed bunch of random files. Apt only handles deb packages, *and nothing else*. It has no idea what to do with a compressed bunch of random files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer procedure given on [this](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) page:

Installing without Internet

To install Wine on an Ubuntu machine without internet access, you must have access to a second Ubuntu machine (or VM) with an internet connection to download the Wine .deb package and its dependencies.

On the machine with internet, add the WineHQ repository and run apt update as described above.

Next, cache just the packages necessary for installing wine, without extracting them:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get --download-only install winehq-devel
sudo apt-get --download-only dist-upgrade
```

Copy all of the .deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives to a USB stick:

```
cp -R /var/cache/apt/archives/ /media/usb-drive/deb-pkgs/
```

Finally, on the machine without internet, install all of the packages from the flash drive:

```
cd /media/usb-drive/deb-pkgs
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

The same instructions can also be used for an offline installation of the `winehq-staging` packages.